# View deployment status in iot edge device

Tags: azure-iot-edge

**Is there any way to see the deployment progress from iot edge device?**

My use case :

> EDGE Device will initiate provisioning.
>   The DPS will start deployment.
>   EDGE Device should display 'deployment complete' message once all modules specified in manifest downloaded.

I know that deployment status can be seen on cloud. but here I need to know it from device.

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? The Edge Agent module is the component that knows when the local config matches the desired config that was deployed to the device, and its logs will have a message indicating this: "Plan execution ended for deployment {n}". If you do `iotedge logs edgeAgent` from the command line, you'll see it. Or you could call `iotedge list` to see the list of running modules. But I'm not sure whether these options meet your requirements...

Comment: @DamonBarry, Is there any API to fetch this deployment status information from edgeAgent?

Comment: No, not that I can think of. You can use the iotedge CLI to list running modules, or to examine edgeAgent logs. You could also use the C service SDK to look at the edgeAgent twin (or to query your deployment job, if you’re doing at-scale deployments). But using the service SDK requires service-level credentials, which you would NOT want to store on the device in a production scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what containers you are expecting to see running, can't you just use the Docker API to query what's running?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ContainerList